# True Type Font not displaying Correctly

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I am trying to get a logo into my PCB design.
I am using Circuit Studio, and have a True Type font with the logo I want as the letter 'a'.

When I use this font elsewhere on my system (ie. word) the logo displays as expected.

When I use the font in CS, It for some reason only displays a portion of the logo (only some of the lettering, not graphic)

The top image is in CS, bottom is same portion in word using the font

[image: Icon Comparison Example]

Comment: You are missing the anti-aliasing effect? It's not possible for a silk screen to my knowledge.

Comment: Can you expand? I'm not sure about anti-aliasing. I have a different TTF with some general PCB warnings/directive that seems to work OK - but I didn't create that font

Comment: Maybe a bitmap import would less a hassle. Just ensure the resolution is fine enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon had multiple 'shadow' layers underneath the lettering and logo. After flattening the icon file, the method to upload inside a TTF works great.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had this exact same issue with some OTF fonts. In addition, for whatever reason Altium allows importing of vector graphics on the schematic but not the PCB editor (bizarre) which would have made life easier.

Anyway, my **workaround** - although far from ideal - was to make the entire logo a single character in a custom font, using the (free) web app [Glyphter](https://glyphter.com).

1. Using Inkscape/Illustrator, type out the whole logo in a new document.
2. Export as SVG 1.0
3. Drag the SVG into an empty cell in Glyphter, and export your custom font.
4. Choose that font in Altium and type the character associated with your logo.

Despite being some legwork to set up, this actually has the advantage of ensuring your logo is 100% perfect and “on brand” every time - no variability in how Altium may track letters, line spacing, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I probably wasn't clear, but that is what I have already got - the whole icon is in the font as the letter 'a' - made with icomoon. I will try using Glyphter instead and see how it goes

Comment: @Thumpers - Aha! In that case there’s a good chance that the graphic (earth icon) within the original vector of the logo wasn’t a properly closed vector shape - one of the anchor points left hanging rather than closed. This can cause some software just to remove chunks of a font rather than deal with hanging shapes. The Glyphter trick may still be if use, but look out for shapes that need closing. If you don’t mind, I’ll leave this answer up as it may be useful to others.

Comment: Thanks @abza, this led me to check icon layers which was the cause for the issues.